# Where are our two pro tem mods?

Tags: discussion, support, status-completed

Two of our pro tem mods are senshin and cheenbabes. There activity log says they are inactive for like 2 weeks.

I know there could be personal problems.
Senshin explicitly stated this in chat with us. But its **2 weeks**. This is not a short time period.

Literally, there is no activity!

Only one mod, Mr. Alien is working hard to patroll the site. This is really worrying, and this is not the way things should work out.

They were assigned on pro-tem basis. So our community mod might contact them... Atleast we need to be explicitly told, like senshin did, that something is wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would like to shower some thoughts over this, if moderators are inactive for a while, there will always be atleast one moderator who will be moderating the site, if not, community managers will keep a check.

There are various reasons for an individual of not staying active, for example, cheenbabes is travelling and senshin has health issues, so users shouldn't worry if at some point, a mod or two are inactive. Site will always be under inspection.

All you need to do is use your privileges and help the moderators, this doesn't apply when mods are inactive for a while but in general, the site has just started, so we have less traffic, once the traffic increases, users having high reputation should start doing thier part as well.

So now all the moderators are active. Lets make the site even better.

Answer (score 6):

Sorry I have been traveling internationally. I should have solid internet access next week.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Now that you have clarified it, its completely fine. Take your time and have a good journey... cheers! :)

Answer (score 4):

Sorry, this was my fault. A number of real-life issues (health issues among them) conspired to keep me more or less away from the computer for the past two or so weeks. I hope that this did not unduly affect the quality of moderation on the site; if it did, I apologize. Thanks to Mr. Alien for continuing to moderate in the meanwhile.

I do not expect this to happen again unless I get hit by a bus or something.

Comment: thats completely fine senshin. I hope you get well soon. Don't take much work on you and treat the site and related work as secondary. Real life, and specially health are far more important, and they and only they should be kept primary. You don't need to apologize at all, and I do remember you mentioning it in chat.